# Free tool to create an online tree diagram that includes links for each element

Tags: gratis, web-apps, hosted, diagram

I draw inspiration from the learning tree diagram by [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/). I would like to create a similar tree for a different subject. Each element should be a clickable link.

**Further criteria:**

- It should be a hosted web app.
- Links should be any kind of hyperlink.
- I don't need to export the created diagram.

**Is there a free tool that allows me to create such an interactive tree diagram online?**

[image: Tree diagram example]

Answer (score 3):

You could try [draw.io](https://www.draw.io), it supports clickable links.

I work on the project.

Comment: Does Draw.io have a template for a tree diagram?

Answer (score 2):

You have a number of choices:

1. You can use [Graphviz](http://graphviz.org/) where you would manually construct a node list, with links, and have graphviz layout your diagram for you and generate an SVG format.  In addition to the offline tool there is an [online version](http://www.webgraphviz.com/) of the graphviz tool *but note that it does not host the image you would still need to post the resulting SVG file to a server and embed it in a web page*. - This will require you gaining some familiarity with the [DOT graph layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language)) language.
2. Offline you can hand draw the tree with [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/), [add the URLs](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Web-Links.html) to go to and save as SVG with the links. The resulting SVG can be embedded into a HTML page and uploaded to your web server.  While this is not an online tool it does allow you to draw rather than code your graph.
3. Online there are a number of free online SVG editors that will allow you to draw your tree diagram some of which allow you to include links for the elements - the one that I am familiar with is [DrawSVG](http://www.drawsvg.org/) which definitely allows the addition of hyperlinks to elements once drawn.

All of the above are free to use. The offline tools are gratis, open source and cross platform.

Comment: The OP said "create such an interactive tree diagram online?" which means "online". Inkscape and Graphviz are wonderful "offline" tools, but not online.

Comment: @bgoodr - At the time that I answered the Further Criteria were not present so there was no requirement for the ___tool___ to be online.

Comment: @steve_barnes, understood!